# Change query on onSelect event with jQuery autocomplete devbridge

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I am building a search input with [jQuery autocomplete devbridge](https://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/). I have run into a problem I cant seem to resolve. I want to update the `query` on the `onSelect` event. But the solutions I have found on the net didn't help me to solve this. Here is my code.

```
$("#assignmentAutocomplete").autocomplete({
  serviceUrl: "/api/CaseManagement/AssignmentAutoComplete",
  onSelect: function (suggestion) {
    var ownerGuid = suggestion.data;    

    // This should update the query param
    $("#assignmentAutocomplete").autocomplete('setOptions', { 
      params: { 
        query: ownerGuid 
      } 
    });    
  }
});
```

I found this solution here: [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27288977/autocomplete-devbridge-update-params-on-change-from-other-autocomplete-field). The autocomplete doesn't initiate a search after the `onSelect` event either.

Comment: Unfortunately its only for the code here on this post. I am using the console and it does't  throw an error. I am using VS 2017.

Comment: Do you find anything in console?

Comment: no sorry. It does't say anything

Comment: Why do you need searchbox after select an item? Onselect is invoke only after selectitem

Comment: Its because I want to grab a Id from the chosen item and send it to the server so I can grab that item specifically and items corresponding to that item.

Comment: Can you provide fiddle of it? Did you able to send server request and receive response?

Comment: The autocomplete works just fine when I type in the search box, but when I select one of the suggestions nothing happens, the query isn't  updating as I want with the provided code.

Comment: Try with "this", I think it may reinitialize.

Comment: it didnt work. Also on the autocomplete dev site it says this about the `onSelect` event: `this inside callback refers to input HtmlElement.`

Comment: Please provide jsfiddle of it.

Answer (score 0):

I could not manipulate the default query param in the `onSelect` but I can manipulate additional params.

```
  $("#assignmentAutocomplete").devbridgeAutocomplete('setOptions', {
                params: {
                    'localUnionId': function () { return SearchObject.SharedVariables.localUnionId; },
                    'OwnerId': function () { return ownerGuid; }
            });
```